# last Item in an array subclass (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, subclass

so I am trying to access the last item in the subclass of the array regardless of the size of the array.

All I got so far was undefined.

```
 var b = [['hello', 'goodbye'], ['hi', 'bye'], ['day', "night"]];

var first = b[0][0];
var last = b[0][b.length-1];
```

Comment: This isn't a subclass.

Comment: There is no subclass in this question. Do you mean the subarray?

Comment: What do you expect the value of `last` to equal? Your question isn't very clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: `b[0][b.length-1]` is `b[0][2]`. As there is no element on index `2` in `b[0]` it will return `undefined` only.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the length of the first dimension, and using it in the second dimension. You need to get the length of the second dimension:

```
var last = b[0][b[0].length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want "night"?

```
var last = b[b.length-1][b[b.length-1].length-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `.length` of the sub array, instead of the parent array. `b.length` refers to the parent/main array

```js
 var b = [['hello', 'goodbye'], ['hi', 'bye'], ['day', "night"]];

var first = b[0][0];
var last = b[0][b[0].length-1];
console.log(last)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have an array b = [] which has elements, which themselves are arrays
b =[[], [], []]

when you do b.length you get the length of the outermost array which in your case is 3, so it basically is doing this

```
b[0][3-1] => b[0][2] which is undefined
```

in languages like Java it would have been [IndexOutOfBoundException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Therefore you need to change your approach to

```
b[0][b[0].length -1]
```

which will give you length of the inner array element, which is 2

```
b[0][2-1] => b[0][1] => 'goodbye'
```